# CSS two columns 100% width with same height (a square)

Tags: html, css, height, width, multiple-columns

Hi i'm trying to create a gridview with two columns with square elements (same width same height dinanicaly,height depend on the width of screen) .This is a working example but the two columns dont cover all the width. Any idea how to do this?

```css
.container{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #0ff;
}

box {
    background:pink;
    margin:2px;
    float:left;
    width:40vw;
    height: 40vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <box></box>
  <box></box>
  <box></box>
  <box></box>
  <box></box>
  <box></box>
  <box></box>
  <box></box>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `width: 40vw;`, they take 40% of the window's width which is 80% each row, so it is expected to leaving another 20% is blank.

What you need is using a `width: 50%;` that makes 2 boxes will fill the full 100%, **but** since they are also having a `margin: 2px`, so you may have to minus 4px from 50% (2px for `margin-left` and 2px for `margin-right`). So that should be `width: calc(50% - 4px);` and beside using a viewpoint unit `vw` in height, I suggest you could use the `padding-bottom: calc(50% - 4px);` which will makes the boxes' height same as their width:

```
box {
    background:pink;
    margin:2px;
    float:left;
    width: calc(50% - 4px);
    padding-bottom: calc(50% - 4px)
}
```

Working JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v8bdmLse/

Comment: thanks man, i have an other question how to set an <img> inside ? I tried this  <box><img src="http://w.....74.jpg"></box> but is not working

Comment: Can it achieve by `background-image`?

Comment: no i need like <img src="..."> inside <box> is it possible? I want to create something similar to a gallery

Comment: Assign `position: relative;` to `box` and `position: absolute;` to `box img` should be okay, check this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/v8bdmLse/1/

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS for `box` is changed according to your requirement

```css
.container{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #0ff;
}

box {
    background:pink;
    margin:1px;
    float:left;
    
    height: 40vw;
    width: calc(50% - 2px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <box></box>
  <box></box>
  <box></box>
  <box></box>
  <box></box>
  <box></box>
  <box></box>
  <box></box>
</div>
```

**Note** :Here your using `float : left` so there is bigger space in right side as compared to left.

Comment: Eeer...the boxes here don't cover all the horizontal space either. All you've done is made them cover slightly more; I'm not sure how this addresses the OP's issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can define width in '%'

```css
  

  .container{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #0ff;
}

box {
    background:pink;
    margin:1%;
    float:left;
    width:48%;
    height: 40vw;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <box></box>
      <box></box>
      <box></box>
      <box></box>
      <box></box>
      <box></box>
      <box></box>
      <box></box>
    </div>
```